# Mysior's example of not completely Hausdorff space

Tags: gn.general-topology, separation-axioms

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-04/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4.pdf

In this link, there is the example of regular space, that is not completely regular. This space is also completely Hausdorff (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516497/is-mysiors-example-completely-hausdorff/3516547#3516547). But in the article, the second page is remark, where is written, that if we add one point b to the space, with its local neighborhoods, that the space is also regular and not completely regular, but also not completely Hausdorff, because there is not the continuous function f, for which f(a)=f(b). I am interested in, how to prove that (that this space is not completely Hausdorff).

Comment: The statement is that for every continuous real $f$ on $X$ we have $f(a)=f(b)$. Hence the conclusion that $X$ is not functionally Hausdorff.

Comment: Its clear, but I cant prove that f(a)=f(b) for every realvalued function. I tried to prove as there is proved that A and a cant be separae by continuous function, that I cant do

Comment: The extended Mysior space is not completely Hausdorff because for any sequence of open sets $(U_n)_{n\in\omega}$ with $+\infty\in U_n\subset\overline U_n\subset U_{n+1}$, the union $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}U_n$ contains the point $-\infty$ in its closure.

Comment: Writing $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ I had in mind the points denoted by $a$ and $b$ in the Mysior's paper. But it it is better to imagine those points $a,b$ as $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Comment: Thank a lot. But I cant understant how that implies that f(a)=f(b) for every realvalued function

Comment: If two points $a,b$ can be separated by a continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ so that $f(a)=1$ and $f(b)=0$, the the sequence of open sets $U_n=\{x\in X:f(x)<\frac23-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\}$ has the required property: $b\in U_n\subset \overline{U}_{n+1}$ and the closure of the set $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}U_n$ is contained in $f^{-1}((-\infty,\frac23])$ and hence does not contain the point $a$.

Comment: So, closure of the union of Un-s contained in f^(−1)((−∞,2/3]) and so f(a) is not 1 because, f(a) is in the closure of union of Un-s. But, sorry, I cant understand why the closure of union of Un-s contains "a". I am in the shame :(

Comment: Just analyze what happens with closures and neighborhoods in the Mysior space: the closure of the strip $[n,+\infty)\times[0,2)$ in the Mysior space adds the set $(n-1,+\infty)\times\{0\}$ and the open neighborhood of $(n-1,+\infty)\times\{0\}$ is the strip $(n-1,+\infty)\times[0,2)$ with finitely many points removed from any vertical segment. Then the closure of the latter set attachs $(n-2,+\infty)\times\{0\}$ minus finitely many points and this process continues to $-\infty$.

Comment: I am thankful very much

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the proof in the paper: if $f(b)<p$ then, by continuity there is an $n$ such that $f(x,0)<p$ for all $x<-n$. The same argument as in the paper now works to establish that $f(a)\le p$. Likewise if $f(b)>p$ then $f(a)\ge p$.